# UWP Scenario - Is there a way to have a UWP app on the same computer both from the Store and from Visual Studio at the same time?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

My question is really simple: I’m a UWP developer and I developed some UWP app for the Win Store.
The problem is that I would want to use these apps on my own too, but I can’t, because I have to have deployed version from Visual Studio for testing new features and new versions.

**To the point... is there a way, for an own UWP app, to have both “Store” and deployed version of it, right on the same PC with the same user?**

Comment: what did you tried, and what error did you get !

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question. But can't you just create a second user account on your PC? So then you will have a Debug account which you can use to run your deployed version for testing purposes. Then you can have the store app on your primary account for personal use. UWP apps are sandboxed so therefor they are only installed per user, not per machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, we could make a project copy, and regard the copy as developer type, open the project with Visual Studio and double click `Package.appxmanifest` file then find Packaging tab option modify the package name to another. click the **Local Machine** button. You will find the new app in the start menu and the app will not override the store version.